# Chromedriver clicks button and submits form but phantomjs doesn't

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone help me with this because it is driving me crazy!

I'm trying to automate this page: http://www.zoopla.co.uk/friend/42816744?section=for-sale&search_identifier=6323219902a84fc51cd97861178ef6ce

For the submit button I've tried using both of these findBy:

> @FindBy(id="friend_submit")
>
> @FindBy(xpath="//input[@type='submit']")

It works fine using ChromeDriver, I can fill in the form and then submit it and see the "Thank you" message on the next page.

The problem is with phantomJS (I'm using webdriverManager so it always downloads the latest version it is currently using ".m2\repository\webdriver\phantomjs\windows\2.5.0\phantomjs.exe") it fills in the form but then clicking the button does nothing.

The next step instead of expecting me to be on the /success/ page I'm still on the form page.

I've tried everything, adding super long waits from clicking to waitng, calling button.submit(); I've even tried clicking the button multiple times while it's still on the page (stupid I know but I've been trying to get this working for hours!)

With ChromeDriver I'm not setting any DesiredCapabilities, but with PhantomJS I've seen a lot of people settings these so I'm currently using:

```
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
    desiredCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, new String[] {"--web-security=false", "--ignore-ssl-errors=true", "--ssl-protocol=any"});
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```

Can anyone suggest why it submits the form in chromeDriver but not phantomJS?

Could it be something to do with how phantomjs renders the page? I'm settings the window size to full screen, I've tried scrolling to the element, if I assert the element is displayed I get true so the button is there its just clicking it (via click or JS) isn't submit the form.

UPDATE:
Ok I might be getting somewhere, I've written a test to submit the form with no data and assert you see the error message on the page, this test passes. It calls the same code to click the submit button.

I've also taken screenshots in the test, the failing one is filling the form in so clicking should take me to the next page. Any ideas why clicking with no data displays the error message but clicking with valid data does nothing?